# Method store() save file to incorrect folder

Tags: php, laravel

In store method i have this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
   $folder = date('d-m-Y');
   $data['thumbnail'] = $request->file('thumbnail')->store("images/{$folder}");
}
```

Default FILESYSTEM_DRIVER is set to PUBLIC
(in .env file there are no FILESYSTEM_DRIVER parmeter)

```
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('uploads'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

When i store file , file stores to folder:

```
public/app/public/images/31-03-2021
```

Why it is not?

```
public/uploads/images/31-03-2021
```

I learn laravel with some old guides, can someone help me to figure out, what i'm miss?
Laravel 8.35
PHP 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried writing in your console
"composer dump-autoload" ?

Comment: never. i try and this give me a error

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php(71): fclose()
`

Comment: Not firing that command is one possible reason what you want to do is not working. Here you can find what it does:
https://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/
If that's not the case, then maybe reseting the caches with php artisan config:cache is another possibility. The error you pasted there is a debuggable error, you probabbly can get it yourself, maybe updating composer itself to 2.0, maybe cleaning cache.

Comment: thank you bro
i just make this command from Open Server terminal
And then , my changes in filesystem driver are affect my project

Comment: np, glad i could help :)